# Unable to run Cucumber using IronRuby

Tags: cucumber, ironruby, gherkin

I'm hoping someone knows the answer to this, I'm running Cucumber from IronRuby and getting an IKVM exception.  Stack trace is at the bottom.  RSpec works fine.

Any ideas?

can't convert Array into java::util::List (TypeError) 
C:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.1.5-universal-dotnet/lib/gherkin/native/ikvm.rb:37:in `new'

C:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:29:in `parse!'

C:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:78:in `configuration'

C:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'

C:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:25:in `execute'

C:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/bin/cucumber:8

Answer (score 1):

I saw [your post in Github](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/gherkin/issues/closed#issue/63). Have you tried to use the [newer version of Gherkin](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/gherkin/downloads) or downgrade to older dependency versions?

Comment: Well, it's currently running on the (2.1.5).  You can see that in the stack trace.  There's one story going around that says gherkin 1.0.27 works, but as far as I can tell that's a native extension, so that makes no sense to me.

Believe me, I've tried _a lot_ of versions.